# Constructing a probability table using data from two trials.

Tags: probability, statistics, data-analysis

so I am struggling to construct a probability table using data from two trials that try to determine the effectiveness of a diagnostic test. I can generate a probability table for each trial separately, but I am required to construct a probability table for the diagnostic test as a whole.

The question is:

> "Bodyworm is a disease that is deadly to adults but not children.
>   Researchers have developed a test to determine if a patient has
>   bodyworm or not. To determine the effectiveness of the test they
>   conducted two trials. In the first trial, 25 known bodyworm patients
>   were given the test, 20 of which returned a positive result. In the
>   second trial, 100 subjects from the general population were chosen. Of
>   these 100, 16 tested positive for bodyworm. Further investigation of
>   these individuals revealed that in fact, only 8 of them had bodyworm."
>
> Construct a probability table for the diagnostic test and hence find the prevalence of bodyworm.

One strategy I considered was combining the two samples into one big sample of 125, but that doesn't seem sensible. I was able to generate a probability table but I feel that it may be wrong. The first trial is a non-representative sample, the other is a representative one, surely you can't just sum them?

Please help! I am so stuck and confused.

Comment: The first study tells us the (experimental) probability that a person will test positive/negative given that she or he has bodyworm.  The second study tells us the probability that a person in the general population will test positive and the (experimental) probability that a person in the general population who tests positive has/does not have bodyworm.

Comment: How do I convert this into a single probability table? I'm not sure where do go from there. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: The first trial is to approx. P(Pos Test | Disease) $\approx$ 20/25; this is called the 'sensitivity' of the test. The 2nd trial is to approx. P(Neg Test | No Dis). How many disease-free people were given the test? How many of them did not get a pos test?  This is called the 'specificity' of the test. The 2nd trial can also be used to approx the 'prevalence' of the disease, P(D) in the gen'l pop: How many of the 100 people has the disease? // Once you have sens., spec., and prev., use Bayes' Thm to find P(Dis | Pos Test). Not sure what 'prob table' is required. Is there exmp of such in text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the event that a person has bloodworm.  Let $P$ be the event that a person tests positive for bloodworm.

The first study tells us that the experimental probability that a person with bloodworm will test positive is $20/25$.  Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(P \mid B) & = \frac{20}{25} = \frac{4}{5}\\
\Pr(P^C \mid B) & = 1 - \frac{4}{5} = \frac{1}{5}
\end{align*}
The second study tell us that the experimental probability that somebody will test positive is $16/100$ and that the experimental probability that a person in the general population who tests positive has bloodworm is $8/16$.  Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(P) & = \frac{16}{100} = \frac{4}{25}\\
\Pr(P^C) & = 1 - \frac{4}{25} = \frac{21}{25}\\
\Pr(B \cap P) & = \frac{8}{100} = \frac{2}{25}\\
\Pr(B^C \cap P) & = \frac{8}{100} = \frac{2}{25}\\
\Pr(B \mid P) & = \frac{8}{16} = \frac{1}{2}\\
\Pr(B^C \mid P) & = \frac{8}{16} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*} 
Since 
$$\Pr(B \cap P) = \Pr(P \mid B)\Pr(B)$$
we can solve for $\Pr(B)$.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(B) & = \frac{\Pr(B \cap P)}{\Pr(P \mid B)}\\
       & = \frac{\frac{2}{25}}{\frac{4}{5}}\\
       & = \frac{2}{25} \cdot \frac{5}{4}\\
       & = \frac{1}{10}
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$\Pr(B^C) = 1 - \frac{1}{10} = \frac{9}{10}$$